# Cassandra DB - Node is down and a request is made to fetch data in that Node

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

If we configured our replication factor in such a way that there are no replica nodes (Data is stored in one place/Node only) and if the Node contains requested data is down, How will the request be handled by Cassandra DB?

Will it return no data or Other nodes gossip and somehow pick up data from failed Node(Storage) and send the required response? If data is picked up, Will data transfer between nodes happen as soon as Node is down(GOSSIP PROTOCOL) or after a request is made?

Have researched for long time on how GOSSIP happens and high availability of Cassandra but was wondering availability of data in case of "No Replicas" since I do not want to waste additional Storage for occasional failures and at the same time, I need availability and No data loss(though delayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say that there is "no replica nodes" you mean that you have set the Replication Factor=1.  In this case if the request is a Read then it will fail, if the request is a write it will be stored as a hint, up to the maximum hint time, and will be replayed.  If the node is down for longer than the hint time then that write will be lost.  [Hinted Handoff: repair during write path](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesHintedHandoff.html?hl=hinted%2Crepair%2Cduring%2Cwrite%2Cpath)

In general only having a single replica of data in your C* cluster goes against some the basic design of how C* is to be used and is an anti-pattern.  Data duplication is a normal and expected part of using C* and is what allows for it's high availability aspects.  Having an RF=1 introduces a single point of failure into the system as the server containing that data can go out for any of a variety of reasons (including things like maintenance) which will cause requests to fail.

If you are truly looking for a solution that provides high availability and no data loss then you need to increase your replication factor (the standard I usually see is RF=3) and setup your clusters hardware in such a manner as to reduce/remove potential single points of failure.

Comment: By request fail you mean querie's response will be empty data or an error? So I am assuming there is no system that automatically starts recovering data from a failed node's storage and distribute until we repair the node and if not repaired, data will be forever lost.

Comment: For any request the query will cause an error as there will not be enough replicas to meet the consistency level of the request.  In case of a write it will still be stored as a hint.  In general what you are trying to do here is an anti-pattern as C* relies on data replication for is high-availability mechanism